# A question on definite integral to find a value, just to confirm myself

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function satisfying $\int_{0}^{f(x)}t^2dt=x^3(1+x)^2$ then what is $f(2)$, what I did: I put $x=2$ both side and got $f(2)=6$, can anyone check it for me?

Comment: linked to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153409/a-question-on-definite-integral-to-find-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you integrate it out, you will get $$\dfrac{f(x)^3}{3} = x^3(1+x)^2$$ Hence, $$f(x)^3 = 3x^3(1+x)^2$$ Setting $x = 2$, gives us $$f(2)^3 = 3 \times 2^3 \times 3^2 = 6^3.$$ Since $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, we get that $f(2) = 6$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{f(x)}t^2dt=\frac{{f(x)}^3}{3}=x^3(1+x)^2$$

$$\Downarrow$$

$${f(x)}^3=3x^3(1+x)^2$$
$$\Downarrow$$

$${f(2)}^3=3 \cdot2^3(1+2)^2=3^3 \cdot 2^3$$
$$\Downarrow$$

$$f(2)=3 \cdot 2 =6$$